# How do I rotate to see my object from a different angle?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I'm a complete beginner to Blender. I would like to know how do I rotate in 3D (to see it from different angles from top bottom and sides) with mouse the initial 3D cube I can see in the initial screen.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! You are asking several questions in one post. Try to limit each post to one question and make several posts with one question each.

Comment: @Timaroberts I cannot add a image showing the deformation of the cube since I do not know how do I achieve it. I just need to slightly move one or two vertices of the perfect cube and then use my mouse to rotate the deformed cube to see it from various angles , from the top and bottom. Anf finally to make a short video of that rotation

Comment: @NajmHoda OK, in the future I'll ask only one question per post though, for my excuse, all these questions in my first post are tightly related.

Comment: @Timaroberts Also I cannot read entire documentation to begin with. I'm reading the book Blender for Dummies but I'm at the very beginning yet. I'm not looking for a command just for the place where I can chceck some button and then see that my mouse rotates the cube slowly.

Comment: @RayMairlot Is it better now ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for making those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Blender. In order to move around the platform full you can hold the middle mouse button down and move if you have a mouse or click and move the top right icon with the z, y, and x axis. The buttons on the number pad can bring you directly to different views such as front top and side views or you can use the <kbd>`</kbd> key and it will give you options.

I highly recommend starting with blender gurus youtube course on making a donut from the beginning as he goes into detail on all of the essential you need to know. Hope this helped.

Comment: Your hint works,thank you. Could you please suggest to me a good video/several videos for a newbie?

Comment: @user2925716 I would recommend Blender Guru's Beginner Series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U It's almost 6 hours long but completely worth watching and following along (Also, most people started with a donut :D)